# view function is not being executed

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, web-development-server

I was trying to make a basic banking system using Django, in which a user can transfer money to other user. But when I tried to transfer money nothing happens, probably because transfer function in **views.py** is not being executed.

Here are **transaction.html** file and transfer function from **views.py** :

**transaction.html**

```
{% extends 'bank/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Transfer Money</h2>
    <form action="{% url 'transaction' %}"  method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <label for="s_acc">Select sender details</label>
      <select  name="s_acc"  required>
        <option value="select">Select</option>
        {% for cust in customer %}
          <option value="{{cust.account_number}}">{{cust.name}}: {{cust.account_number}} : {{cust.balance}}</option>
        {% endfor %}

      </select>
      <br>

      <label for="amt">Enter amount</label>
      <input type="number" name="amt" required>
      <br>

      <label for="r_acc">Select receiver details</label>
      <select  name="r_acc" required>
        <option value="select">Select</option>
        {% for cust in customer %}
          <option value="{{cust.account_number}}">{{cust.name}}: {{cust.account_number}} : {{cust.balance}}</option>
        {% endfor %}

      </select>
      <br>

      <button type="submit" name="button">TRANSFER</button>

    </form>

  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

**transfer function from views.py:**

```
def Transfer(request):
    customer = Customer.objects.all();
    if request.method=="POST":
        s_acc = request.POST.get('s_acc')
        amt = request.POST.get('amt')
        r_acc = request.POST.get('r_acc')
        print(s_acc)
        print(amt)
        print(r_acc)
        amt = int(amt)

        if((s_acc=='select')or(amt=='select')or(r_acc=='select')or(s_acc==r_acc)):
            messages.warning(request,"Account not selected or both the accounts are same")
        elif(amt<=0):
            messages.warning(request,"Enter valid amount")
        else:
            for c in customer:
                if(c.account_number == s_acc):
                    s_name = c.name;
                    if(amt>c.balance):
                        messages.warning(request,"Insufficient balance")
                    break

        for x in customer:
            if(x.account_number == r_acc):
                r_name = x.name
                r_bal = x.balance
                break;

        for c in customer:
            if c.account_number == s_acc and r_acc!=s_acc and r_acc!= 'select' and amt<=c.balance and amt>0:
                q1 = Transaction(sender_name = s_name, amount = amt, receiver_name = r_name )
                q1.save()
                acc_bal = c.balance - amt
                q2 = Customer.objects.filter(account_number = s_acc).update(balance = acc_bal)
                q2.save()
                acc_bal = r_bal+amt
                q3 = Customer.objects.filter(account_number = r_acc).update(balance = acc_bal)
                q3.save()
                messages.success(request,"Transfer Complete")
                return redirect('tranfer_list')
    return render(request,'bank/transaction.html',{'customer':customer})
```

**urls.py**

```html
from django.urls import path
from bank import views

urlpatterns = [
        path('',views.AboutView.as_view(),name = 'about' ),
        path('about/', views.AboutView.as_view(),name = 'about'),
        path('customers/', views.CustomerListView.as_view(),name = 'customer_list'),
        path('transfer_list/', views.TransactionListView.as_view(), name = 'transfer_list'),
        path('transaction/', views.Transfer, name = 'transaction'),
        path('customers/new', views.CustomerCreateView, name = 'customer_new'),

]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to add `action` attribute to the form

Comment: Hello @PriyanshuGupta You have to specify **URL** if your form `action` and have to create URL's for your view `Transfer`

Comment: And if you want to validate user input for example `s_acc=='select'` you can use not keyword to validate your input it will return **True** if input is empty or null. eg. `if not s_acc`

Comment: @AnkitTiwari I had created URL of view transfer in my urls.py file

Comment: @RezaHeydari could please elaborate why i have to add action attribute? as i have added required urls in the views.py function

Comment: Your form need to now submit to which view

Comment: You can read about django form [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/)

Comment: Here is a short summary  form is your client side or you can say frontend and your `views.py` and `urls.py` is your server side or you can say backend, so when form is submitted than all the form data is stored so to communicate with server or to send data to server we have to provide URL in form action so it can reach that particular view to do some stuff.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari here I'm using templates , which can be directly linked to views using render

Comment: Hello @PriyanshuGupta no the actual process is you have a function inside your `views.py` which can be accessed by it's endpoint which you have created in `urls.py` when you go to that particular url the given view will get called and what ever you have to send as  response you send from your view in your case you are rendering your template.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari yes i followed the same process , but still nothing is happening after the submission of the form

Comment: hello @AnkitTiwari I have added **urls.py** code in the post too , I had previously followed the same process as you have told now.

Comment: Hello @PriyanshuGupta add this in side your form action `action="{% url 'transaction' %}"`

Comment: @AnkitTiwari same issue is occurring i.e transfer function is not executing, even after adding the form action told by you

Comment: Hello @PriyanshuGupta [edit] your question as per code and information provided by me.

Comment: Hello @PriyanshuGupta when you submit your form what happens.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari when i submit the form ,nothing happens , the page just refreshes and the value in the form is again set to default.

Comment: Hello @PriyanshuGupta did you have any **CSS** class to your form tag? because in some of the free template call ajax call using a class so you have any class to your form

Comment: and check your terminal that these are getting printed or not `print(s_acc)`
        `print(amt)`
        `print(r_acc)`

Comment: hello @AnkitTiwari I checked the terminal, these print statements are getting printed and I haven't use any **CSS** class in the form tag

Comment: As you can see given print statement getting execute that means your function is called on post method you have to check any logical error inside your function. Why you are using `break` is you want to do nothing use `pass`

Comment: and `return redirect('tranfer_list')` indent it properly.

Comment: hello @AnkitTiwari thanks for the support, I will look into logical errors in the transfer function and get back to you if again the problem occurs.